# Copy VM with Import-VM or New-VM?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v, cloning

I am writing a PowerShell script to clone existing hyper-v VMs/ create new VMs based on a template. Where ever I look the cmdlets `Export-VM` and `Import-VM` are used. However the cmdlet `New-VM` has the option to use an existing VHD aswell. Wouldn't just copying the VHD and creating a `New-VM` be easier? It's just 1 file instead of VHD + Virtual Machine Folder + setting a new Snapshot folder. (The Template has no Snapshots)

What are the advantages of using `Import-VM` over `New-VM`? Are there any or is this *primary opinion based*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A VM consists of two different parts

1. The Virtual HardDisk files (one or multiple) that hold the OS and data
2. The configuration of the VM within Hyper-V, including the virtualized hardware available to the VM.

If you just copy a VHDX file and use `New-VM` you only get the first part of the original VM. Sure you can try to use parameters on `New-VM` to make the new VM similar to the original one, but you may miss something.

Using `Export-VM` and `Import-VM` you copy both parts of the VM.

Comment: So if I want to set the CPU and RAM in the Script `New-VM` might indeed be perferable? I guess software registrations might get invalid by `New-VM` due to new Hardware IDs but might stay valid with `Import-VM -GenerateNewId` because it changes just the ID of the VM for Hyper-V and the MAC?

Comment: @T-Me yes, and if you copy the VM to another host, keeping the original ID can be helpful.